# OpenGL ES 2.0 - How to efficiently copy a Texture into Frame Buffer

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0, libvlc

In short - I have an OpenGL texture which I need to copy into a FBO or another texture in the most efficient way possible under OpenGL ES 2.0.

At the moment I'm simply drawing the first texture into an FBO.

Is there a more efficient way? E.g. some sort of pixel copy that doesn't involve pulling the pixel data back to RAM and then buffering over to another texture - in ES 2.0 profile.

To give you context - this is video rendering related:

I have an OpenGL texture being buffered with video frame data from LibVLC, but due to timing issues between my app redraw rate and the decoder refresh rate, its possible that the OpenGL texture has no new frame to update & very oddly if I were to draw the texture to the screen without a frame to update - instead of it containing the previous frame's data, it draws some weird image of its own ( it looks like a space invader ?? ) - hence why I need to 'cache' the previous frame's content.

Specifically, this is an OpenGL texture, used to create an Android SurfaceTexture, which I have to call updateTexImage and releaseTexImage manually to either update the Texture's content and then to mark that I'm done with the SurfaceTexture's content once I've drawn it. If I don't release it then no new frames can be updated to it. If I release it I can't redraw the same frame more than once. Which has lead me to caching the texture once it's updated so the decoder is free to write to it & I still have the previous frame if when I come to draw again & there hasn't been an update yet.

Thanks.

Comment: Amusingly, I've just fixed my issue by finally figuring out how to handle the Android SurfaceTexture updateTexImage and releaseTexImage methods within my app by allowing the onFrameAvailable callback to release then update and giving it the GLContent to enable it to do so. I don't need to cache anymore (yay!) but I'd still be interested in any answers.

Comment: at all the same, you should post your solution as an answers as well.

Comment: What about `glCopyTexImage2D`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is based on having worked out how to properly interface with the Android SurfaceTexture to avoid having to cache its contents altogether.

If anyone wants to share an answer regarding efficient texture copies in OpenGL ES 2.0 please feel free - that would befit my original question.

For anyone interested, this is what I did:

My GLPaint class for rendering video on Android contains the SurfaceTexture instance, it's created from a JOGL OpenGL Texture ( using it's ID ) - This enables me to draw the texture as part of my GLPaint.paint function.

This GLPaint implements the onFrameAvailable method of the SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener interface. I have a private boolean to flag when the first frame has been 'written' - this is needed to avoid releasing the SurfaceTexture prematurely.

The class GUIThreadLock is my extension of a ReentrantLock - I extended it for additional debugging info and to make a static singleton. This lock in my 'one in - one out' controller for threads in my UI, ensuring only a single thread is active in my UI at a time ( usually just the main renderer looper ) but also handles getting the OpenGL context bound or unbound to the lock owner thread whenever one acquires and relinquishes the lock respectively.

```
@Override
    public void onFrameAvailable( SurfaceTexture pSurfaceTexture )
    {
        try
        {
            GUIThreadLock.acquire();
            if( written )
            {
                pSurfaceTexture.releaseTexImage();
            }
            pSurfaceTexture.updateTexImage();
            written = true;
        }
        finally
        {
            GUIThreadLock.relinquish();
        }
    }
```

This means that when a new frame is ready, the SurfaceTexture releases the old one & updates to the new one - it is then buffered with the current frame for any point I wish to draw the video until the next frame is ready. The GUIThreadLock protects the SurfaceTexture from updating the content while I may be drawing it but also acquires my GL Context so that the callback thread can actually perform the update here.

My Redraw thread would also require the GUIThreadLock before it could draw my app - thus the GL context is protected and the relationship between frame updates and frame draws cemented.

Comment: While this is a cool solution, do you have any proof of it being more efficient drawing the first picture to FBO?

Comment: If you were using a texture backed FBO, you could pass the TextureID of that to create the Android SurfaceTexture object mentioned here & it would work the same way but give you a FBO rather than just the Texture. As to copying the data - I don't have any proof, only the assertion that copying the data from the SurfaceTexture ( remembering its an OpenGL Texture in a different guise ) to another OpenGL Texture on-top of what's already happening above then its simply more ops-per-frame. The solution above is a procedural solution with regards as to how to integrate the AndroidSurface Texture.

Comment: I agree on "more ops per frame". If that is your definition of efficient you probably made a more efficient solution. Not so sure if it is faster because of thread context switching overhead. I'd like to know your performance results for each solution.

Comment: You make a good point about the context switching - I haven't looked into how involved that process is so it indeed might prove to be costly. I'll try and see if I can re-work the process so that the SurfaceTexture.onFrameAvailable callback simply flags that an update to the surface texture is needed & stick to doing the actual update in my main draw cycle - avoiding making the context current on different threads & the locking. I tried this once before but was unsuccessful which lead me down the road of looking to copy the texture data. I'll try to test the performance of each.